# Result ListView not Showing from JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm new in android, and now I'm trying to showing data into my listview from JSON using Volley, my code doesn't have any error, but the data from JSON not showing in my app. I don't know where the error of this code bellow is my method that make it in MainActivity.java and I have put the loadGalangDana() method into onCreate and my data in Listview doesn't show the result.

**This is my method in MainActivity.java**

```
private void loadGalangDana() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onResponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    setValueArtikelAwalList = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray galang_danaArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"datas",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    for (int i = 0; i < galang_danaArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject galang_danaObject = galang_danaArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        SetValue_ArtikelAwal galang_danaitem = new SetValue_ArtikelAwal(
                                galang_danaObject.getInt("id_galang_dana"),
                                galang_danaObject.getString("judul"),
                                galang_danaObject.getString("deskripsi"),
                                galang_danaObject.getString("tgl_galang_dana"),
                                galang_danaObject.getString("imageId"),
                                galang_danaObject.getInt("durasi"),
                                galang_danaObject.getInt("terkumpul")
                        );
                        setValueArtikelAwalList.add(galang_danaitem);
                    }
                    ListViewArrayAdapter adapter = new ListViewArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),setValueArtikelAwalList);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

**This is my adapter.java**

```
package com.example.project;

public class SetValue_ArtikelAwal {
    private int id_galang_dana;
    private String imageId;
    private int terkumpul;
    private String judul;
    private int durasi;
    private String tgl_galang;
    private String deskripsi;

    public SetValue_ArtikelAwal(int id_galang_dana, String judul, String deskripsi, String tgl_galang, String
            imageId, int durasi, int terkumpul) {

        this.id_galang_dana = id_galang_dana;
        this.judul = judul;
        this.deskripsi = deskripsi;
        this.tgl_galang = tgl_galang;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.durasi = durasi;
        this.terkumpul = terkumpul;


    }
    public int getId_galang_dana() {
        return id_galang_dana;
    }
    public int getTerkumpul() {
        return terkumpul; }

    public int getDurasi() {
        return durasi; }

    public String getJudul() {
        return judul;
    }

    public String getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public String getDeskripsi() {
        return deskripsi;
    }

    public String getTgl_galang() {
        return tgl_galang;
    }
}
```

in my app, there no error, but the data not showing, please help me to fix this

```
UPDATE
this is the log when i run the app

2019-12-25 21:32:26.954 10988-11271/com.example.project D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-12-25 21:32:27.105 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for imageId
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.example.project.MainActivity$5.onResponse(MainActivity.java:301)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.example.project.MainActivity$5.onResponse(MainActivity.java:283)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.106 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.107 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.107 10988-10988/com.example.project W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2019-12-25 21:32:27.123 10988-10988/com.example.project I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.project, PackageName:com.example.project
2019-12-25 21:32:32.018 10988-11062/com.example.project V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2019-12-25 21:32:33.001 10988-10988/com.example.project W/BoostFramework: Slow Operation: BoostFramework perfHint took 24ms
2019-12-25 21:34:27.323 10988-11280/com.example.project W/DpmTcmClient: Couldn't find 'tcm' socket after 120times. quit trying
2019-12-25 21:34:59.767 10988-11736/com.example.project V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 152880
2019-12-25 21:34:59.802 10988-11736/com.example.project V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-12-25 21:34:59.864 10988-11736/com.example.project V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1376757754
2019-12-25 21:34:59.921 10988-11736/com.example.project D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=152880, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-7432507192535428376}]
2019-12-25 21:35:00.081 10988-11736/com.example.project V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-12-25 21:35:00.082 10988-11736/com.example.project D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-12-25 21:35:00.083 10988-11736/com.example.project V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2019-12-25 21:35:01.872 10988-11736/com.example.project D/FA: Application backgrounded
2019-12-25 21:35:01.923 10988-11736/com.example.project D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_background(_ab), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto}]
2019-12-25 21:35:07.096 10988-11736/com.example.project V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: share your json response

Comment: where can i know the json response ? in the logcat ?

Comment: i've been update question and put the log, please check it

Comment: this is log messages. which tells that you are accessing key without value. Please print response object when successful api calls. You are getting exception while parsing JSON.

Comment: Either you share your API URL or share response data of your API then only exact problem can be addressed currently problem is in parsing response data